# Trying to convert an image to a Stream for use with Spire.Barcode ScanStream functionality

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, barcode, bytesio

I am currently creating a application which can read barcodes from images and then display the images.

I am using Spire.Barcode as my library as it seems to have the best recognition rate.
Currently I have to load the image twice, once to scan for a barcode then a second time to load it into the UI

The user selects a folder, then all the images in the folder are scanned for a barcode, then opened again, resized and saved into memory to be displayed in the UI

```py
def scan_single_image_for_barcode(image_path):
    try:
        barcode = spire.BarcodeScanner.ScanFileWithBarCodeType(image_path, spire.BarCodeType.Code39)
        print(f"Barcode From spire= {barcode} and barcode {barcode[0]}")
        if barcode[0] is not None:
            barcode = barcode[0]
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error scanning image '{image_path}': {e}")
        barcode = None
    return barcode
```

The image_path points to the image.

I was hoping there is a way to instead load the image once, pass the image data to the scanner, and then resize and store the data.

Spire does have a function called ScanStream but so far every way I have tried to convert the image to a stream/bytes hasn't worked with the most common error being
`'_io.BytesIO' object has no attribute 'Ptr'`
I think it may be something to do with Spire.Barcode being a C Library.

I have tried to use io.BytesIO. I have used PILs built in toBytes() function.
I have tried to google this and looked at documentation but I really have no idea.

Not really sure where to go from here.
Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can't find any package called spire that scans barcode in python.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/Spire.Barcode/. Theres a link to the library if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you are creating a BytesIO stream. However, Spire.Barcode for Python uses a different Stream object. You can adjust your code according to the following example:

```
from spire.barcode import *

image_path = "Code39.png"

with open(image_path, "rb") as file:
    image_bytes = file.read()

stream = Stream(image_bytes)

scan_result = BarcodeScanner.ScanOneStream(stream)

print(scan_result)
```

Here is my result:

[image]

Btw, the **BarcodeScanner** class of Spire.Barcode for Python provides several functions for scanning barcodes from streams. You can choose an appropriate one according to your needs.
[image]